# Javascript elementary recursive output returning undefined answer

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a program that takes in a "base" and "exponent" from the user and outputs "base * base * base * base" for as many exponents as we need.  I.e. 2^3 outputs "2*2*2."  However, I am currently getting "undefined*undefined*undefined*undefined...."  Where is my simple mistake?

I am guessing its a small issue with this function:

```
    function display(base, expo)
            {
                if (expo == 1)
                {
                    document.getElementById("outputfield").value = document.getElementById("outputfield").value + base;
                }

                else
                {
                    document.getElementById("outputfield").value = document.getElementById("outputfield").value + base + "*";
                    display(base, expo--)
                }
            }
```

Here is the whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            var base = document.getElementById("base").value;
            var expo = document.getElementById("expo").value;

            function display(base, expo)
            {
                if (expo == 1)
                {
                    document.getElementById("outputfield").value = document.getElementById("outputfield").value + base;
                }

                else
                {
                    document.getElementById("outputfield").value = document.getElementById("outputfield").value + base + "*";
                    display(base, expo--)
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#">
            <p><label>Please enter a Base Number: 
                <input id = "base" type="number"><br>
                and an Exponent:
                <input id = "expo" type ="number" ><br>
                <button id="calculate" onclick= "display()">Calculate</button>
                </label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <output id="outputfield" type = "text"></output>
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: because you don't pass in any values: `onclick= "display()"`, but your function expects passed values `function display(base, expo)`. Note function arguments override variables with the same name in outer scopes

Answer (score 0):

You can define display function like this

```
function display (base, expo) {
    return expo === 1 ? base.toString() : base.toString() + "*" + display(base, expo - 1);
}
```

And use it like this

```
document.getElementById("outputfield").value = display(base, expo);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call for first time the function `display` u need to pass the input values as arguments, then i prefer use a preview function to get the input values,  inside it u can call the recursive function like here:

```js
var base = document.getElementById("base");
var expo = document.getElementById("expo");
var output = document.getElementById("outputfield");

function resolve() {
  output.innerHTML = ""
  output.innerHTML = display(base.value, expo.value)
}

function display(base, expo) {
  return parseInt(expo) === 1 ? base : `${base}*${display(base, --expo)}`
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
    <p><label>Please enter a Base Number: 
        <input id ="base" type="number"><br>
        and an Exponent:
        <input id ="expo" type ="number"><br>
        <button id="calculate" type="button" onclick= "resolve()">Calculate</button>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <output id="outputfield" type="text"></output>
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the 'base' and 'input' variables inside the function worked for me, you need to reassign the current value of the 'expo' input field on every function call though.

```
 function display(){

      var base = document.getElementById("base").value;
      var expo = document.getElementById("expo").value;

      if (expo == 1){
          document.getElementById("outputfield").value = document.getElementById("outputfield").value + base;
      }   
      else{ 
          document.getElementById("outputfield").value = document.getElementById("outputfield").value + base + "*";
          document.getElementById("expo").value = --expo;
          display(base, --expo)
      }
  }
```